# GoogleService-Info.plist for both Analytics and SignIn

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-analytics, google-signin

While setting up the Google SignIn to the current project I had to generate GoogleService-Info.plist and successfully did it but now I want to integrate Google Analytics too and so for that again the googleServices plist need to be generated again so will there will be any conflict for this two plists and is there any way to use single plist for both frameworks.

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
by the way the account for both frameworks are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you already added Google SignIn in the project with GoogleService-Info.plist then you just need to add **TRACKING_ID** in the GoogleService-Info.plist for integrate Google Analytics (Both using same account). Everything in the GoogleService-Info.plist generated for the same as Google SignIn GoogleService-Info.plist with addition of **TRACKING_ID**.

copy from GoogleService-Info.plist of Google Analytics.

```
<key>TRACKING_ID</key><string>Your Tracking</string>
<key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key><true/>
```

**Edit Update** : Try this

For this case you need use different Targets with diff bundle id in project for **Dev** and **Prod**.
After that you will can link `GoogleService-info.plist` for this targets. And also I recommend create different folders in project directory 
Look at pictures. The first you create targets **Prod** and **Dev**

[image]

After create diff folders in project dict let's call them **GoogleProd** and **GoogleDev** and copy your `.plist` file to diff folders and drag to project. First file you need link with `TestProd target`

[image]

And the second file link with `TestDev target`

[image]

The final project directory will look like

[image]

Comment: actually the issue here is there are two different accounts and so PROJECT_ID, GOOGLE_APP_ID are all different

Comment: @VinodRathod wait let me check for different account.